# SpatiaLite AddGeometry not accepting a variable

Tags: python, spatialite, sqlite

I have a program that asks users to browse for a .csv of X and Y points and then prompts the user via a sg.popup to enter a SRID (SRS) captured as string variable 'EPSG_Code'.
Once entered I'd like to use that SRID to add a geometry column to the data of the initial CSV and turned into a SpatiaLite DB table.

My problem I'm getting is while trying to pass 'EPSG_Code', Addgeometry doesn't seem to work.
The end result is a table with ID, X, Y and no geometry column with the following error
"OperationalError: table data_wGIS has no column named geometry"

```
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    con.enable_load_extension(True)
    con.load_extension("mod_spatialite")
    con.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);")
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    #GIS ONLY TABLE
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_wGIS (ID REAL PRIMARY KEY, X DOUBLE DEFAULT 0, Y DOUBLE DEFAULT 0)')
#This is the part that appears to be incorrect.
    cur.execute('SELECT AddGeometryColumn("data_wGIS", "geometry" , ? , "POINT", 0)',(EPSG_Code,))

    #Adding support for SpatialIndex-Queries
    cur.execute('SELECT CreateSpatialIndex("data_wGIS","geometry")')
    #Insert XY data
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO data_wGIS(ID, X,Y,geometry) SELECT ID, X,Y, MakePoint(X,Y,?) FROM db_data_Clean', (EPSG_Code,))
    con.commit()
```

For all of this I'm using Python, SQLite, SpatiaLite. Eventually this will have more 'daily' CSV X and Y points to be added to it.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) that I thought would help me to pass the variable over with the "?" but I do feel I'm missing something obvious. I've replaced the SRID in testing with an integer and it works and I've also tried passing the variable as a list. This also didn't work.

```
t_EPSG_Code = [EPSG_Code]
```

Comment: >.< my EPSG_Code that was entered is a string - all I had to do was convert the EPSG_Code to an int and the AddGeometry accepted it. Working well! Thanks for the edit @Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
EPSG_Code = int(EPSG_Code)
```

Apparently there is no error thrown when SpatiaLite needs an integer and not a string.

Comment: By https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html `the return type is Integer, with a return value of 1 for TRUE or 0 for FALSE` but you don't seem to check it.